# how do i search a 2d list to be able to play rock, paper, scissors?

Tags: python, list, search, 2d

still kinda new to this site (sorry if i messed up) so my homework for the week is working with lists...
my professor wants me to modify my rock, paper, Scissors game to use a 2d list. which i was able to make. the rest is the problem. i need to search the 2d list for the outcome, and post if the player won or the computer, and keep track of the number of wins each has, until the player doesn't want to play anymore. i've looked and tried two different ways to do a search but i either end up in an endless loop or it ends without doing anything... right now i'm stuck with an endless loop. the output is easy part i think.

This is my current code after doing multiple re-writes... i have everything else from the old version that doesn't use a list commented out so i didn't post it.

```
compchoice = " "
humwin = 0
compwin = 0
again = 'Y'
playing = True
outcomes = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2], [1, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
#thelist = []
#thelist.append("Player 1 = {playerchoice}, Player 2 = {compchoice}")
while playing:
    playerpic = int(input("Pick 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, or 3 for Scissors: "))
    comppic = random.randint(1, 3)
    pick = [playerpic, comppic]
    for x in range(len(outcomes)):
        for i in range(len(outcomes[x])):
            if pick == outcomes[x][i]:
                print("You chose Rock.")
                print("Computer choose Paper")
                print("You lost")
                compwin += 1
                print("Human: ", humwin, "  Computer: ", compwin)
                break
#will not break, seems to ignore if? missing something!
```

Comment: `pick = [playerpic, comppic]` pick is a list.  But `outcomes[x][i]` is a single integer.  Of course those two things are not equal.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: There's no need to loop over `outcomes[x]`. You just want `if pick == outcomes[x]:`

Comment: Why do you always write that the player chose `Rock` and the computer chose `Paper` no matter what they actually chose?

Comment: So far you 2d list doesn't seem to know anything about wins and losses. Maybe there's another approach which incorporates that naturally. For example, a 2d list of -1s, 0s and 1s where x-coordinate is player's pick and y-coordinate is computer's pick: `[[0, 1, -1], [-1, 0, 1], [1, -1, 0]]`, where `-1` is player loses, `0` is draw, `1` is player wins.

Comment: Or you could have 3 lists. One list for human wins, another list for computer wins, and a third list for ties. `if pick in human_wins: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have all the possible combinations that the player and computer can choose.  It just appears that these choices need to be categorized into the ones where the computer is the winner, the ones where the player is the winner, and the ones that are ties.  Also, it appeared that there needed to be an added bit to prompt the user as to when the game would conclude.  With those additional bits, following is one possible refactored version of the code.

```
import random

compchoice = " "
humwin = 0
compwin = 0
again = 'Y'
playing = True
choice = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
outcomes = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2], [1, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
#thelist = []
#thelist.append("Player 1 = {playerchoice}, Player 2 = {compchoice}")
while playing:
    playerpic = int(input("Pick 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, or 3 for Scissors: "))
    comppic = random.randint(1, 3)
    pick = [playerpic, comppic]
    for x in range(len(outcomes)):
        if pick == outcomes[x]:
            print("You chose", choice[playerpic - 1])
            print("Computer choose", choice[comppic - 1])
            if (x < 3):             # In those choice combos, the computer wins
                print("You lost")
                compwin += 1
            elif (x < 6):           # In choices 4 - 6, the player wins
                print("You won")
                humwin += 1
            else:                   # The last three combos are a tie
                print("Tie")
            print("Human: ", humwin, "  Computer: ", compwin)   # List the current score

    cont = input("Play again Y/N ") # Need to ask a question to continue playing

    if (cont != 'Y'):
        break
```

The things to note:

- The various choice combinations are categorized based on who wins or if there is a tie.
- Instead of outputting "1/2/3", the selections are given a descriptive output.
- And, the user is prompted to see if they wish to continue playing.

Testing out this refactored code, following is some sample terminal output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Games$ python3 RockPaperScissors.py 
Pick 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, or 3 for Scissors: 1
You chose Rock
Computer choose Scissors
You won
Human:  1   Computer:  0
Play again Y/N Y
Pick 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, or 3 for Scissors: 1
You chose Rock
Computer choose Rock
Tie
Human:  1   Computer:  0
Play again Y/N Y
Pick 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, or 3 for Scissors: 3
You chose Scissors
Computer choose Rock
You lost
Human:  1   Computer:  1
Play again Y/N N
```

Go ahead and dissect this and hopefully get a better understanding of lists and tests.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it as you did. i'm new to Python, so explanations such as this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would split the problem up in a couple steps:

1. Let the player select rock/paper/scissors
2. Let the computer select rock/paper/scissors
3. Select the corresponding matchup from a 2D list based on 1. and 2.
4. Display the result

You have 1. and 2. figured out. The question is... how should you design your 2D list?

I think it would make sense that you use the player and computer input to select the result: so

```
result = my_2d_list[player_choice][computer_choice]
```

What would you expect the output of `result` to be? What would this list have to look like to output this result using `player_choice` and `computer_choice` as indices?